# Mockito when() in parallel stream unexpected result

Tags: java, mockito

I was investigating Mockito's behavior in one of our tests and I didn't understand its behavior. The following code snippets shows the same behavior :

```
@Test
public void test(){
    var mymock = Mockito.mock(Object.class);
    var l = List.of(1,2,3);
    l.parallelStream().forEach(val -> {
        int finalI = val;
        doAnswer(invocationOnMock -> {
            log.info("{}",finalI);
            return null;
        }).when(mymock).toString();
        mymock.toString();
    });
}
```

The output I was expecting is prints of 1,2,3 in some order (not nessaseraly sorted) :

The output I received :

```
2
2
2
```

Why I got this output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic race condition: your parallel stream executes the `forEach` lambda three times in parallel. In this case, all three threads managed to execute the `doAnswer()` call, before any of them got to the `mymock.toString()` line. It also just so happens that the execution where `val=2` happened to run last. Happily, Mockito is reasonably thread-safe, so you don't just get exceptions thrown.

One way your scenario might occur is if the threads happened to run like this:

1. Main thread: calls `l.parallelStream().forEach()`, which spawns 3 threads with `val` equal to 1, 2 and 3
2. val=1 thread: executes `finalI=val`, giving it a value of 1 in this thread
3. val=2 thread: executes `finalI=val`, giving it a value of 2 in this thread
4. val=3 thread: executes `finalI=val`, giving it a value of 3 in this thread
5. val=3 thread: calls `doAnswer(...)` which makes future calls to `mymock.toString()` print out `3`
6. val=1 thread: calls `doAnswer(...)` which makes future calls to `mymock.toString()` print out `1`
7. val=2 thread: calls `doAnswer(...)` which makes future calls to `mymock.toString()` print out `2`
8. val=1 thread: calls `mymock.toString()`, which prints out `2`
9. val=2 thread: calls `mymock.toString()`, which prints out `2`
10. val=3 thread: calls `mymock.toString()`, which prints out `2`

Note that this isn't necessarily happening in order, or even in *this* order:

- some parts of this may literally be happening at the same time, in different cores of your processor.
- while any steps within a single thread would always run in order, they might run before, after, or interleaved with any steps from any other thread.

Because the threads are running in parallel, and you have not put anything in place to manage this, there is no guarantee whatsoever about the order in which these calls occur: your output could just as easily have been `1 1 1`, `1 2 3`, `3 2 1` or `3 2 2` or `1 1 3` etc.

Comment: I understand that order is not guaranteed but I was expecting every stream to handle only 1 of the values and not 3 values as you mentioned. Why I see only the prints of the last run ?

Comment: I've added more details, hope that helps

Comment: Why did you mention that calling doAnswer(..) actually prints something ? In all the scenarios that I run this code, i had only 3 prints to the screen and it was the same value. From what I know, the doAnswer() and when are mockito functions that keep some global variables, it shouldnt actually run the method under when(..)

Comment: Read it carefully - I did not say that `doAnswer()` prints anything: I said that "doAnswer() makes *future calls* to `mymock.toString()` print out X". The last `doAnswer()` call to run just happened to be the one for val=2, and so all three subsequent calls to `mymock.toString()` print out 2.